# Random Image rotation that doesn't repeat image

Tags: javascript, random, rotator

I'm modifying an image rotator that also chooses the images at random from a UL. My aim is to have all LI chosen without repeats. My approach has been to add .remove class once the .show class is done, then in the random math var, not select the .remove class.

The slight problem I'm having with the following code is that occasionally, the .show class is not applied to a LI and it goes through that cycle without an image. Eventually, all images show, then receive the "remove" class, and there are no repeats, but I would like to always have one li.show so there isn't a blank.

I have very minimal JS knowledge, so if this approach seems wrong, I welcome alternatives, but it seems like there is just something simple I'm overlooking.

Thanks.

```
function theRotator() {
    $('div#box1.rotator li').css({
        opacity: 0.0
    });
    $('div#box1.rotator li:first').css({
        opacity: 1.0
    });
    setInterval('rotate()', 25000);

}

function rotate() {
    var current = ($('div#box1.rotator li.show') ? $('div#box1.rotator li.show') : $('div#box1.rotator li:first'));

    if (current.length == 0) current = $('div#box1.rotator li:first');

    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('div#box1.rotator li:first') : current.next()) : $('div#box1.rotator li:first'));

    //Un-comment the 3 lines below to get the images in random order
    var sibs = current.siblings();
    var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * sibs.length);
    var next = $(sibs[rndNum]).not('.remove'); //HERE I ADDED: .not('.remove')
    next.css({
        opacity: 0.0
    }).addClass('show').animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 10000);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({
        opacity: 0.0
    }, 10000).removeClass('show').addClass('remove'); //AND HERE I ADD THE REMOVE CLASS AFTER SHOW...
};
```

Sample structure of the HTML:

```
<div id="box1" class="rotator">
    <ul>
        <li class="show">
            <img src="images/006.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/014.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/019.jpg" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd try `sibs = current.siblings().not('.remove')` and randomly select one of those, rather than selecting a random sibling first and then applying `.not()`. Though having said that, I'd probably implement the whole thing differently: I'd randomly re-sort the entire set of items before starting the rotation, and then just iterate through the random set in its new order. On reaching the end just re-sort, rinse, repeat.

Comment: nnnnnn. Thank you. That solved the problem. final code for the randomizer is:`code` var sibs = current.siblings().not('.remove');
        var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * sibs.length );
        var next = $( sibs[ rndNum ] );